# PHP pagination active page number not highlighted

Tags: php, css

I am trying to have the active page number highlighted, but having no success in getting to work. Can anyone help please.

this is the CSS for the pagination

```
.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
}   
.pagination a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.pagination a.active {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
}

.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}
```

This the pagination code :

```
<div class="pagination">
<?php
    $get = $_GET; 
    $current_page = isset($get['page'])?$get['page'] : 1;

    for($i=1;$i<=$tpages;$i++) {

        $get['page'] = $i; // set the page parameter

        $qs = http_build_query($get,'','&amp;');
        if($i==$current_page) {
            echo "current_page $current_page <br />";
            $pagLink .= "<class='active'><a href='despatchdata_results.php?$qs'>$i</a>";
        }else{
            $pagLink .= "<a href='despatchdata_results.php?$qs'>$i</a>";
        } 
?>  
</div>
```

Comment: This `<class='active'><a href='despatchdata_results.php?$qs'>$i</a>` is not HTML. `<a class="active" href='despatchdata_results.php?$qs'>$i</a>` this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
 $pagLink .= "<class='active'><a href='despatchdata_results.php?$qs'>$i</a>";
```

is malformed. 
Your `active` style applies to the `a` element (`a` inherits the `active` class, as you can see in the CSS definition of the style `a.active`)

Try this:

```
 $pagLink .= "<a class='active' href='despatchdata_results.php?$qs'>$i</a>";
```

and let me know if it solves it

Comment: Thanks I put the class='active' inside the a tag and the active page is now highlighted

Comment: great! remember, `class` is always an attribute of an html element, not an element by itself. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the class name inside of the a tag, for example;

```
<a class=“classname”>Link text</a>
```

Comment: yes, that's the issue. Although since this is a learning opportunity for the OP and whoever googles this in the future, it'd be nice to explain "why" :)

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS does not match your generated HTML, also your HTML is not valid:

```
.pagination .active a {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
}

.pagination div:not(.active) a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
```

and update your generated HTML with:

```
$pagLink .= "<div class='active'><a href='despatchdata_results.php?$qs'>$i</a></div>";
```